# Need to rest jboss admin password (no add-user.sh)

Tags: redhat, jboss, password-reset

I need to access the JBoss AS Administration Console:

`myserver101:11090/admin-console`

mserver101 is a RHEL virtual server

However I do not have the username/password credentials. I have tried the obvious one, e.g. admin/admin, Administrator/password etc. but I cannot get it.

I checked in `$JBOSS_HOME\bin` but I do not have the script, `add-user.sh`

Can anyone tell me how I could get the credentials to log in or otherwise obtain access to the admin console?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you changed your security configuration for management interface, then the Admin Console is secured using `ManagementRealm`

```
<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
  <authentication>
     <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
     <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
      <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
  </authorization>
</security-realm>
```

The credential files referenced here are either in `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuraiton` of `JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration` depending on whether you run in standalone or domain mode.

Now you did not mentioned, if there is already some user, and you just do not know the password, or if there is no management user yet. The passwords in `mgmt-users.properties` are encrypted(or better said hashed). The easiest solution is to add a new entry into the file - for example generate a new user on your local machine via `add-user.sh` and just copy the line from your local `mgmt-users.properties` to the remote server. Then you can use the newly created username/password.